# Construction of a sequence of continuous functions that are pairwise separated by 1 in the uniform norm

Tags: functions, continuity

I need to construct a sequence of continuous functions $f_n\in C[a,b]$ such that for each $n\neq m \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\left \| f_n-f_{m} \right \|_\infty = 1$

I can totally understand how to draw such series, but I lack the knowledge on how to construct it.

Heres my drawing:[image]

Hope it's understandable. The upper bound is 1.

Comment: You are looking for a *sequence* of function, not a *series*, FYI.

Comment: @KeeferRowan Sorry, automatically translated it to my mother's tongue where sequence and - series are the same word.

Comment: No worries, just thought I'd let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG suppose we are working on $[0,1]$. All other cases are similar.

Split $[0,1]$ in $E_n:= [\frac{1}{2n+2}, \frac{1}{2n}]$ and $F_n := [\frac{1}{2n+1.5}, \frac{1}{2n + 0.5}]$. Then $F_n \subseteq E_n$ for each $n$. Then for each $n$, define $f_n: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ by $f_n = 0$ on $E_n^C$, $f_n = 1$ on $F_n$ and $f_n$ is linear in between (i.e. draw a line from the left endpoint of $E_n$ to the left endpoint of $F_n$ and a line from the right endpoint of $F_n$ to the right endpoint $E_n$). Then the $f_n$ are continuous functions that are 0 outside of $E_n$ and $1$ somewhere in $E_n$. But note that $m\neq n$ implies $F_n \cap E_m = \emptyset$ so $\|f_n -f_m\|_\infty \geq 1$ (since for $x \in F_n$, $f_n(x) =1$ but $f_m(x) = 0$). But also since $f_j$ has codomain $[0,1]$, $\|f_n -f_m\|_\infty \leq 1$. So $\|f_n - f_m\|_\infty = 1$.

Edit:

Explicit formula for $f_n$.

$$f_n = \begin{cases}
 0 & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2n+2}\\
 \left(\frac{1}{2n+1.5} - \frac{1}{2n+2}\right)^{-1}(x-\frac{1}{2n+2}) & \frac{1}{2n+2} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2n+1.5} \\
1 & \frac{1}{2n+1.5} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2n+0.5} \\
\left(\frac{1}{2n+0.5} - \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{-1}(x-\frac{1}{2n+0.5}) +1 & \frac{1}{2n+0.5} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2n} \\
0 & \frac{1}{2n} \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Thats a good start.
However, I would like to see how to build such function explicitly on $[a,b]$ and also - how to write that "linear line" in a form of a real function..

Comment: I mean it has all the essential details. If you want to write up for like a HW solution or something, you could more be more explicit about what these function are: just define them piecewise. It is intuitively clearly without explicit formulae though. Has your question been resolved? If so, please mark as accepted.

Comment: I guess I can write it out if you are having trouble.

Comment: Thats very kind! it could be great

Comment: @vpam Added, you can check that everything agrees on the overlap, hence we have continuity. You might also see why it's nice to avoid working with these formulae.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$F(x) = \begin{cases} 
0  & x\le a \\
\frac{x-a}{b-a} & a \le x \le b \\
1 & x \ge b
\end{cases}$$
And define $$F_n(x)=F[n(x - a) + a]$$
Not exactly like the ones you drew but very close and the idea is the same.